# Dart tear-off const constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

In Dart, let's say I have the following class
`class MyClass { const MyClass(); }`

If I have a property of another class that accepts `Widget Function() someProperty`,
I am used to saying `someProperty: () => const MyClass()` but I am wondering, if I say
`someProperty: MyClass.new` will MyClass be called using its const constructor, Or will it always be called using its default (non-const) constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tear-off will always construct a non-`const` object.  When you create the tear-off, there's no way to know if it will later be invoked with `const` or non-`const` arguments.  There's also no way to specify that a tear-off should be restricted to be invoked with only `const` arguments.  Since the tear-off is a `Function` object and is variable, there's no way to know if it's a tear-off to a `const` constructor and can be invoked in a `const` context, so you can't specify `const` when invoking the tear-off either.

You can take advantage of `const` objects (usually) being canonicalized to test this yourself:

```dart
class MyClass {
  const MyClass();
}

void main() {
  var f1 = () => const MyClass();
  var f2 = MyClass.new;

  print(identical(f1(), f1())); // Prints: true
  print(identical(f2(), f2())); // Prints: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `someProperty: () => const MyClass()`, it calls the const constructor of `MyClass`. However, if you use someProperty: `MyClass.new`, it will call the default (non-const) constructor of `MyClass`.

The const keyword creates immutable objects and can be evaluated at compile time. When you use `const MyClass()`, you are invoking the const constructor of `MyClass`, which creates a compile-time constant instance of the class.

Using `MyClass.new` invokes the default constructor of `MyClass`, which creates a regular instance of the class. This instance is not evaluated as a compile-time constant and can be mutable.

Summary:
If you want ensure that the const constructor of MyClass is called, you need to explicitly use `someProperty: () => const MyClass()`.

Some code snippet:

```
class MyClass extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyClass();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text('Hello, World!'),
    );
  }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
  final Widget Function() someProperty;

  SomeOtherClass({required this.someProperty});
}

void main() {
  final instance = SomeOtherClass(
    someProperty: () => const MyClass(),
  );

  final widget = instance.someProperty();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: widget,
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It `MyClass` class will only called it's constructor `MyClass()`. Either you add `const` keyword or not add that keyword. Both constructor are the only the one.

Adding `const` in front of the constructor is Dart language special feature (Pragmatics) not to compile every time when calling constructor.

If you are not little bit clear by using `const` keyword. I want to reference this tutorial.
https://resocoder.com/2020/01/06/dart-const-tutorial-all-you-need-to-know-const-expressions-canonical-instances-and-more/